# link/Button which move to relevant section on page

Tags: custom-button, page-layout, custom-link

Aim – To add an anchor link called “AUM link” in the Section called“Operational. Section "Operation" is on the Account object and on the pagelayout "Client".

Once you click on link i want it so it navigates down to the related list called CDR

Object : Account
Record type : Client
Page layout : Client

Related list : CDR
Label : CDR
Master Object : Account

Currently the page layout is the standard page layout, ideally I don’t want to go down the VF route. 
Really appreciate your assistance on this

Regards
M

Comment: DO you have the CDR related list on the page layout? On which object do you want to add the link and what is the relationship between the object you are going to add the link and the related list object? Could you explain?

Comment: HI Shailesh Patil udpated main post

Answer (score 1):

This is a JS hack. But may give you the result you wanted. 
 - Create a Custom Link on account object
- Give it any name behaviour will be "Execute Javascript" 
- Enter the bellow JS code and hit save
`window.open("/{!Account.Id}#{!Account.Id}_00N90000002kavt_target","_parent")`
Note: 
1) You see the ID which is given in bold italics. To get the ID, go to the CDR object through Create-->Objects
2) Go the Custom Field Account which is a lookup field
3) In the URL, you will get the ID of the custom field. Just put this ID value in the above javascript. 
[image]
 Let me know your result. :) 
 Thanks!

Comment: HI Shailesh Pati. Thanks for providing that solution, that indeed works, however as its a custom link i cant add it to required section. Any ideas, how i can get around that ?

Comment: Well, I don't think it is possible. Another way I was thinking is through the inlinne VF page which will not work due to cross domain problem. Only way is to add a custom link somehow.

Comment: HI Shailesh Patil i had another thought, this could be acheived by a custom s controller, but i know salesforce no longer supports them